# Parse SOAP Response in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, soap

How can I parse the following soap response string to c# objects and get the values of "applicationUrl" and "applicationValue"?

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
<env:Header>
</env:Header>
<env:Body>
    <ns2:getAdvertisementsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.mrted.com/">
        <ns2:advertisementResult>
            <advertisements>
                <advertisement>
                    <applicationUrl>
                        http://test.com
                    </applicationUrl>
                    <applicationValue>
                        test
                    </applicationValue>
                </advertisement>
            </advertisements>
            <totalResults>2</totalResults>
        </ns2:advertisementResult>
    </ns2:getAdvertisementsResponse>
</env:Body>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the service provider is giving you a WSDL, the first thing I would try is the Web Services Description Language Tool (Wsdl.exe):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.80).aspx

> The Web Services Description Language tool generates code for XML Web
>   services and XML Web service clients from WSDL contract files, XSD
>   schemas, and .discomap discovery documents.

Comment: Note that this is also possible using the [Add service reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) inside Visual Studio.